# Strong attribute on NSArray and retain cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I'm making an iOS app in which i have an `Event` class and a `Participant` class.

The `Event` class as an `NSArray *participants` property with a `strong` attribute.
The `Participant` class needs to have a property refering to the event the participant is in.

I'm asking myself if the fact that the participants array as a `strong` attribute implies that each participants in this NSArray also as a strong attribute ? Therefore, does the event property of the `Participant` class needs to have a `weak` attribute to avoid a retain cycle ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the `Participant` class should have a weak reference to its `Event` if your `Event` class has a strong reference to its `Participant`'s. However, you have mistaken the strong attribute of your `NSArray` to mean that the array holds a strong reference to each `Participant`. An NSArray will ALWAYS maintain a strong reference to the items its holds. It is the `Event` class's reference to its array that is strong.

Comment: Be aware that changing the reference to the participants array to weak will NOT prevent the retain cycle.

Comment: Yes I see, i wasn't aware that NSArray always as a strong reference to it's objects. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the inverse relationship (participant -> event) should be `weak`, and since a participant cannot exist without the event, this would cause no problem. Meaning that if you remove the event, the participants will be deallocated automatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an `NSArray` `strong`, **you are retaining the reference at that array**.
Is the `NSArray` that **retains objects in itself**.

And **YES**, to avoid `retain cycle` if the `object A retains B`, `B` should just have a **`weak`** `reference to A`. But be careful to the management of the object in that array.

Finally i can't figure out your structure, but maybe the `participants` array is of objects `Participant`?

Consider the possibility to use `Delegation` pattern or `KVO`.